# asynchronous javascript best practices

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, express

Using node.js/express.js, here is an example of a typical problem that I face with asynchronous code (function rendering a page on a request with 2 db call):

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
        data1: getData1(),
        data2: getData2()
    });
};
```

Here is what one function could look like:

```
function getData1() {
    var assets = db.get("assets");
    assets.find().on('success', function (docs) {
        // What to do ?
    });
}
```

I tried using async.js which is a very helpful module, but I'm still missing knowledge on how to do  with a case like this.

And can someone suggest good resources for best practice regarding asynchronous javascript coding ?

Comment: You may want to also look at jquery's deferred object http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an asynchronous workflow library, such as [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

```
function getData1(done) {
    var assets = db.get('assets');
    assets.find().on('success', done);
}

function getData2(done) {
    var assets2 = db.get('assets2');
    assets2.find().on('success', done);
}

exports.index = function(req, res, next){
    async.parallel({
        d1: getData1,
        d2: getData2
    }, render);

    function render (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        res.render('index', {
            data1: data.d1,
            data2: data.d2
        });
    });
};
```

In this way, you can stick to the `callback(err, result)` style perpetrated throughout Node packages, while keeping your code sane and pretty. [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) provides methods to simplify your workflows. In this case, I used the `async.parallel` method which allows you to run any amount of callbacks concurrently, and then runs the function provided as a second argument when the other callbacks is done.

Comment: Thanks Nico, I like the approach with async. Do it means that in getData  I have to call `assets.find().on('success', done(err, queyrresult));` ? If so, it doesn't make the functions getData really reusable, right ?

Comment: You can just pass the `done` callback, as in `.on('success', done)`, because it has the `(err, result)` signature you describe. They're completely reusable because you can use those same queries in other contexts where you need to do `getData1` or `2`

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem would be to chain the asynchronous commands by passing a callback function to the functions performing the asynchronous operations:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    getData1(function (data1) {
        getData2(function (data2) {
            res.render('index', {
                data1: data1,
                data2: data2
            });
        });
    });
};

function getData1(callback) {
    var assets = db.get("assets");
    assets.find().on('success', callback);
}
// Similarly for getData2
```

However, the nested callbacks can become unmanageable quickly. You can name the functions to help with this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var data2Success = function (data1, data2) {
        res.render('index', {
            data1: data1,
            data2: data2
        });
    },
    data1Success = function (data1) {
        getData2(data2Success.bind(this, data1));
    };

    getData1(data1Success);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do one of the following:

**1) Nest your calls:**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  //first call
  assets.getRecord(function (err, docs) {

    // 2nd call
    assets.getSomeOtherRecord(function (err, otherDocs) {
        res.render('index', {
          data1:docs,
          data2: otherDocs
        });
    );

  });

};
```

If your code is simple, and you don't mind running these one after the other, then this suffices. If those don't apply, I use approach #2:

2) Use async.js or Q as the other answers here show.

**Resources for learning about async:**
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/managing-the-asynchronous-nature-of-node-js/
- http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice

Comment: Thanks Jamis, 1) is definitely not a way that I want to go with as my two db query will not be reusable at all. Thanks for the resources!